# Writing subscriber for turtlebot (C++)

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone help me (maybe already have) writing a simple program to subscribe to TutleBotSensorState and use  a callback function to display some of the data, for example temperature.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62717/writing-subscriber-for-turtlebot-(c++)/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [the tutorial on writing a C++ subscriber](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on 2013-05-15**:
Of course I have read this part of the tutorial and I know how to write subscribers for turtlesim. I am interested in knowing how to write the callback method for turtlebot.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-27**:
You need to change the include line to point to the message header, and then change the datatype of the callback function. And you should make sure to have the dependency on the package as well.

**Comment by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on 2013-05-28**:
header and dependencies are set appropriately, but when I try my callback I get errors. Could you give a specific sample callback function for turtlebot.